# winapi how to change a windows resource language programatically

Tags: c, winapi, assembly, data-structures, modern-ui

trying to change resource languages into an exe/dll file programatically, I've tried to do that with `UpdateResource` but it doesn't work since the language per item is not part of the resource template, it seems to be in a structure caller `RESOURCEHEADER` which is located at the beginning of each resource type...

Thus accessing to this part seems to be a bit complicated, no API to do that.

The only thing left would be to reverse engineer the structure and update the binary directly, but I prefer asking before.

Comment: You might have better luck if you explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: trying to change the resource languages into an exe/dll file programatically, to change a resource like a dialog you need to do a beginupdateresource/updateresource/endupdateresoure but doing this doesn't allow you to change the language of this resource...

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to happen. Have you read [The Resource Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? From my experience creating a mui app in WPF, the standard behavior makes you restart the application for the change to take effect. I followed [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization) to get it working on the fly.

Comment: winapi, nothing to do with wpf, what i'm trying to do is not in the resource reference.

Comment: You might want to look at that link again, the resource reference **is for the winapi**.

Comment: I know this resource reference by heart, it's not what I was expecting, thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Are you saying that you have resources in Language A, and you want to change those resources so that they're in Language B and update the header to reflect the new language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think why you'd want to do this, but anyway...

Call

```
UpdateResource(hUpdate, lpType, lpName, wOldLanguage,  0, 0);
```

to delete the existing language resource and

```
UpdateResource(hUpdate, lpType, lpName, wNewLanguage, lpData, cbData);
```

to write a new resource with the new language identifier, where `lpData` and `cbData` refer to a copy of the existing resource data.

Note that it gets a lot more complicated if you are using MUI.  The [`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs have the details.

Comment: actually most of the dll exe files are false multilanguage dll/exe since the developers carelessly put different language perr dialogs/stringtables etc ... thus when I run muicrt tool to generate a mui files it tells me that it cannot proceed on multilanguage dlls... so I'm making a console tool to cahange the languages into one only... Thanks this answers to my question ...

Comment: I'm happy to help.  Rather than editing the title, you can indicate that the question is solved by clicking the tick to the left of the answer.

Comment: @user please accept the answer, I rolled back your question edit. Accepting is the correct way to acknowledge this.